# ckan.plugins.core.PluginNotFoundException: geo_view

Tags: python, ckan

As per instructions I followed the steps on https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-geoview

However I encountered the error: error message:

> ckan.plugins.core.PluginNotFoundException: geo_view

I followed forums on Stack Overflow to help me. But I still encounter the same error.

To install ckanext-geoview on a production site:

Activate your CKAN virtual environment, for example:

```
source /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
```

Install the ckanext-geoview Python package into your virtual environment:

```
pip install ckanext-geoview
```

Add the relevant plugins to the ckan.plugins setting in your CKAN config file (by default the config file is located at /etc/ckan/default/production.ini). Check Available plugins to see which ones are available and if they require further configuration.

Add the resource_proxy plugin to the ckan.plugins setting.

Restart CKAN. For example if you've deployed CKAN with Apache on Ubuntu:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PluginNotFoundException when installing CKAN extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952108/pluginnotfoundexception-when-installing-ckan-extension)

Comment: use `python setup.py develop` inside the extension directory where `setup.py` exists. (assuming you activate the ckan python venv before this)